# How can I remove inventory items in a Bukkit plugin?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

I am making a Bukkit plugin that takes the player to a "FunZone" and allows them to do just about anything. I don't want data transferred between the two worlds. So far I have got most everything stopped. Here's the problem code:

```
            Integer normInvSize = player.getInventory().getSize();
            Integer i = 0;
            for (i=0; i<normInvSize; i++) {
                ItemStack item = player.getInventory().getItem(i);
                pConfig.set(player.getWorld().getName()+"Inv."+i.toString()+".amount", item.getAmount());
                Short durab = item.getDurability();
                pConfig.set(player.getWorld().getName()+"Inv."+i.toString()+".durabillity", durab.intValue());
                pConfig.set(player.getWorld().getName()+"Inv."+i.toString()+".type", item.getTypeId());
                player.getInventory().removeItem(new ItemStack(item.getType(), item.getAmount()));
            }
```

I have everything set up how I want it but I get stray items following me between the worlds. The line

```
player.getInventory().removeItem(new ItemStack(item.getType(), item.getAmount()));
```

does not remove all of the inventory. I want some code that will remove all inventory items (I've handled armor already). I already have a way to restore the inventory later, but my code currently won't remove everything. For example I can end up transfering some stone tools from the "FunZone" to the normal world, which I don't want.

Comment: Did you try to delete the item directly with player.getInventory().removeItem(item) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't clear a list while you're iterating over it, at least not in this way. Let me show you this, we'll assume a list with 5 items:

1. List: 5, Index: 0
2. List: 4, Index: 1
3. List: 3, Index: 2
4. Break condition already met. 2 Items remaining.

What you want to do is clear the whole inventory *after* you've iterated over it.

```
// Cache the inventory instead of a number you'll only use once.
PlayerInventory inventory = player.getInventory();

// Cache the world name
String worldName = player.getWorld().getName();

// Use a foreach instead. Looks better.
for (ItemStack stack : inventory.getContents()) {
    // More cache, String concetanations are expensive!
    String start = worldName + "Inv." + Integer.toString(i);

    pConfig.set(start + ".amount", stack.getAmount());
    pConfig.set(start + ".durability", stack.getDurability().intValue()); // Please be aware that I fixed a typo in durability
    pConfig.set(start + ".type", stack.getTypeId());
}

// And now clear the inventory
inventory.clear();
```

Also, I don't know what `pConfig` is, but the structure smells broken if you need save stuff like this. You use an Object-Oriented language, so if you need to split strings to get *something*, you're doing something wrong. You might want to rewrite that...thing.

For further infos please go to Stack Overflow, f.e.: [Efficient Equivalent to Removing while Iterating a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/java-efficient-equivalent-to-removing-while-iterating-a-collection)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help pConfig is my player config file is looks like this:      File saveFile = new File(this.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "players", player.getName() + ".yml");                     FileConfiguration pConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(saveFile);

Comment: Also i am very new to java i have been working on it for maybe a couple of weeks so im sure there are plenty better ways of doing things then how i do it. Long story short i am storing the players loc and inv from the world they came. And then when they leave fz(funzone) save inv and loc there. Then teleport and restore. As i said i have this all laid out already teleport inv save and fetch but removeing was not working.And Thanks to this suggestion i can now ride the unused slots (b4 i was saving all inv even blank slots). Then i need to work on armor and exp

Comment: Um i have a prob the ItemStack stack : inventory.getItems() does not work

Comment: @HcgRandon: Typo on my end.

Comment: yeah i got it all fixed